# Multiple Bindings in DataTrigger

Tags: xml, xamarin

I currently use two `DataTrigger` for my `Label` element. As you can see in the below code, one of them is rather redundant:

```
<Label Text="123" TextDecorations="Underline" TextColor="White" Margin="0,5,0,0" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="1"> 
    <Label.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger TargetType="Label" Binding="{Binding isVisible}" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="IsVisible" Value="True" />
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger TargetType="Label" Binding="{Binding isVisible}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="IsVisible" Value="False" />
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger TargetType="Label" Binding="{Binding isConnecting}" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="IsVisible" Value="True" />
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger TargetType="Label" Binding="{Binding isConnecting}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="IsVisible" Value="False" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Label.Triggers>
</Label>
```

It would be ideal if i could bind `isVisible` and `isConnecting` in the same triggers.
Is that achievable?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can bind `isVisible` and `isConnecting` in the same triggers. But if you give a default value to your Label, you codes would look not so redundant, for example:

```
<Label Text="123" IsVisible="False" TextDecorations="Underline" TextColor="Black" Margin="0,5,0,0" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" >
    <Label.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger TargetType="Label" Binding="{Binding isVisible}" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="IsVisible" Value="True" />
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger TargetType="Label" Binding="{Binding isConnecting}" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="IsVisible" Value="True" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Label.Triggers>
</Label>
```

BTW, why are you binding `isVisible` to `isVisible` of the same label?(If I understand correct)